# How to get a thread state from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a class which creates threads, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("[Thread] info: " + t.toString());

    r = new rt(t.get(i).getGridPath(), t.get(i).getIdTower());
    Thread rThread = new Thread(r);
    rThread.start();
    pids.add(rThread.getName());         
}     

gUp = new gridUpdate(pids); 
Thread updateGrid = new Thread(gUp);
updateGrid.start();
```

The function of **updateGrid** thread is check if the status of the each rThread is TERMINATED. When it is true, updateGrid does a bunch of function.

How can i get the state of each **rThread** from **updateGrid** class?

Take a note that im passing the threads PID for the constructor and inside of run() method i have this statement, but always return NEW meaning that it is new thread.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {             
    t = new Thread(pids.get(i));                
    System.out.println(t.getState());
}
```

Comment: why are you creating list of thread names, create a list of threads and get that thread , to call getState()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @svasa commented, I changed the List type from `List<String>` to `List<Thread>` and added each Thread to List, like:

```
pids.add(rThread);
```

So, its done!

Thanks @svasa!